# We're going to upgrade the Help Center page, here is the 100,000-foot-view discussion of the what-we-cans and what-we-can'ts

Tags: discussion, help-center, 2024-hc-redesign

@HDE226868 has agreed to help us update the Help Center pages. I believe it's time for a fairly thorough review of what we want for the next stage in the Stack's lifespan. It's an opportunity we're not going to get very often. Consequently, the process will be intentionally time-consuming with each "phase" of the discussion taking 2-4 weeks.

This is the kick-off for the effort and I'd love to have as many of our users as we can join in. Heck, it might be against policy, but I have no problem suggesting that the following comment be pasted to questions and answers of users (arbitrarily) 10,000 rep and higher. (Others will see the link and join us, which is great! But we need to draw a line or we'll be posting this in millions of places.)

> The Community is starting the process of updating our Tour and primary Help Center page. This will include policy decisions and it's a great opportunity to help us define the next stage of [worldbuilding.se]. Please join us at [this Meta page](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10334/40609) and share your thoughts. Thanks!

**What is the 100,000 foot view?**

- There are things we can't do.
- There are things we can do.
- There are things we can do if we're clever.

**What can we edit?**

We can edit...

1. Some of the Tour (it's not very flexible).
2. Some aspects of the [front page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) (which is even less flexible).
3. The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Basically, we have one page to work with. The relevant movie quote is, "We've got to find a way to make this... fit into the hole for this... using nothing but that."

**Request for High-Level Section Ideas**

Today the "What topics can I ask about here?" page has the following general sections:

> **INTRODUCTION**
>
> - Who we serve.
> - What "worldbuilding" means to us.
> - What worldbuilding vs. storybuilding (one sentence).
> - No character decisions here (specialized storybuilding).
>
> **ASKING QUESTIONS**
>
> - What, why, how, and research.
> - Sample topics (*really* old question examples).
> - Another we-don't-do-storybuilding sentence.
> - How to ask about events.
>
> **SITE RESOURCES**
>
> - The Sandbox
> - The Perfect Question checklist
> - Real-World Questions
> - More "how to ask about events"
>
> **THE SMALL PRINT**
>
> - Specific & answerable, good/bad subjective
> - Flagging questions

**My Proposed Goals...**

1. At this point in time, everything is up for grabs. However, I believe it makes more sense to start from the top and work down. That page needs to be clean, clear, and preferably short. That means it's ultimately going to be a bullet list of concepts with brief statements and links to Meta pages that explain all the gory details.
2. Which means we need to be careful which rabbits to chase. We'll be compromising across a lot of opinions with the goal of setting up a help center page we can be proud of for the next 7-8 years. If any of us nudges another with a comment like, "that's a discussion for later," we need to be ready to take a step back.

Therefore, this first discussion is...

**What are the *high-level sections* that this page should have including a description of their content and, if appropriate, examples?**

*Please post answers with ONE PROPOSED SECTION PER ANSWER. That way comment discussions can be focused. Remember, there are things we can do if we're clever, meaning the Help Center is authoritative so long as it links to the necessary policy pages, which I think also need to be looked at. But, one thing at a time.*

One more thing. This is the first step in a somewhat complicated process. If you think this is the wrong first step, don't be shy... post and answer and explain why we should be focusing somewhere else first. I've been in business meetings where the first day was spent figuring out where to start. Relevant book quote, "A beginning is the time for taking the most delicate care that the balances are correct."

Comment: Incidentally, I think the sandbox is a symptom of the problem of Worldbuilding. "Worldbuilding: the stack with rules so contrary, arbitrary and up for interpretation, that the only way to know if your question is okay is to ask it in a sandbox so people can tell you if it's okay to ask it." If we had better rules, more clearly defined, we would not need a "sandbox". What other sites do? (I did a spotcheck. I could not find any other site that felt it needed a meta sandbox just so people could get their questions approved for asking. Tis a silly place.)

Comment: @JamieB This is the first post of a process that will take several months at least to complete. If, in the course of that effort, you can find a way of dealing with the Stack Exchange-mandated "Opinion-Based" close reason without resorting to the use of a Sandbox, we'll be glad to entertain your ideas. Some of the problems have nothing at all to do with our policies or culture.

Comment: @JamieB Also... [Math has a sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/463082) • [RPG prefers independent meta posts after-the-fact](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7371/43046) and there's [Codegolf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) • [CS Ed](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202) • [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129) • [Islam](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966) • [Politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5832/20391) • [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276).

Comment: @JamieB So... what symptom do all those site have in common with us that they also need sandboxes? Other than it's a convenient way to help new users acclimate to Stack Exchange, not just the individual sites, I mean. Maybe they're all silly, too.

Comment: Sandbox for Math clearly says it's for drafting complex problems. Not because they might get voted closed, but because the user may want to do multiple revisions before finalizing a post. Very different reason than here. RPG specifically says "no sandbox". Codegolf is for posting challenges and people want to refine their challenges. I guess the short version is *those sandboxes are a friendly aid for the community*. Our sandbox is more of a bludgeon. "Use this or else we might find some infraction and close your question and you'll never guess what our declared infraction might be."

Comment: @JamieB Is there real value to this debate? Perfect equations, perfect challenges, I mentioned RPG went another way..., perfect questions.... What's the difference between their friendly aid and our friendly aid? Frankly, shame on you for asserting that an honest effort to help people learn how to use the site is a *punishment,* no matter what you, personally, think of its rules or moderation. Here we are at the beginning of an equally honest effort to recraft the site's culture... *and you're whining.* You're welcome, BTW, and even invited to help, but I hope for less whining.

Comment: Math's sandbox is a friendly aid. Literally a favor to the community, to cover a weakness in the SE interface -- the drafting of difficult questions that may require multiple edits to get right. Your WB sandbox presents itself as a courtroom where you may sit in judgement of people's posts, telling them if they have permission to use the real site. That's not a friendly aid. Better defined rules -- and an aim to be a friendlier, more productive Stack -- would make that room unnecessary.

Comment: @JamieB "My" sandbox? I didn't create the sandbox, I'm just the latest caretaker. It's been around much longer than I've been a member of the community. Historical links exist on the sandbox page. You're wrong too often to be taken seriously.

Comment: @JamieB I have no desire to be a moderator - and by "other users" you primarily mean yourself. We celebrate free speech here, but to be honest, if you can't positively contribute to a better world. Have the courtesy to be silent.

Answer (score 13):

#### Creativity vs Science Lite

Somewhere in this discussion and definitely in the who we are / what we do sections, we really need to stress that worldbuilding is a creative endeavour and that we encourage questions that demonstrate creativity and also elicit creative responses.

We must stress that we are **NOT** physics.lite.se and that questions and answers do not have to couched in terms of real world science or follow the realist school.

Unfortunately, WB.SE has morphed quite a bit since its inception. To quote Separatrix from a recent response here:

> WB has changed, a lot, several times. The stack I joined isn't the one you joined, I was already fading out as you became active. The stack as it is now isn't that one either. I miss the one I joined, but that's long gone. Fundamentally most of the questions when I started were either story based or opinion based requiring creative solutions. Everything is now much stricter, it's more about maths problems that can be solved, heading for "I can't be bothered to categorise this properly for another stack" questions rather than the considerably more creative place it used to be. (Separatrix)

I would like to focus on this aspect: **story based or opinion based requiring creative solutions**. This alone is why I joined and stayed and remained active. If this place continues on the path to convergence with the science forums and continues to push away the creative aspects of the art, then there's no longer any use for this forum.

Here is a good example question: [Determining the qualities of a quill based on the qualities of the bird](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/254499/determining-the-qualities-of-a-quill-based-on-the-qualities-of-the-bird). This is a worldbuilding question that, as I read it, touches potentially on in world natural philosophy / science; in world folklore & culture; in world magic and  underlying principles. In the comments we find many typically "science lite" complaints:

> What makes you think flamingos eat microbes? Seeing as how these birds are nominally able to fly, why would you think their feathers would be different from those of other wading birds? (Eg. flamingos.)
>
> Using quills for writing with ink on paper was a strictly European thing, limited in time from the Middle Ages to the Early Modern period. In the Antiquity, they used reed pens, and reed pens continued to be used in the Islamic world throughout the period when Christian Europe used feather quills. Goose, swan, and chicken quills worked just fine and were interchangeable. The only requirement was for the primary flight feathers to be large enough; even the feathers of large crows or ravens worked all right. There were no major material differences.
>
> I guess that the difference between the Classical Antiquity and the Islamic world where they used reed pens on one hand, and Christian Europe where they used quill pens on the other, is the lack of suitable reeds in colder climates... For the same reason nobody has tried flamingo quills -- there are few place with flamingoes but no reeds.
>
> It took me no time at all using Google to discover a great variety of bird primary feathers were used as quill pens and that Ostriches prove that a quill pen could be made from the primary feathers of a flightless bird. Research is mandatory.

Another query: [Is there a way to offset the damage caused by breaking cosmic strings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/255845/is-there-a-way-to-offset-the-gravitational-waves-created-by-breaking-cosmic-stri)

> Cosmic string are nothing more than fictional objects devised by some people who cannot even agree on a way to verify their theories. You can build all and nothing on them.
>
> Do you know that the amplitude of gravitational wave wanes quickly due to geometrical spreading but I will need to check if it also experiences attenuation.

These kinds of comments seem somewhat to considerably unhelpful in a creative sense. For the first question, we note that the OP did not ask for materials science or physics or biology; so we are not dealing with a sciency answer. If anything, the wording of some *quality of the bird* leads to a particular *quality of the quill* leads one naturally to consider a more esoteric, more philosophical answer. And since the OP is specifically not asking for a scientific answer, clearly, the answer needs to be more creative in nature. For the second question, the OP touches on highly theoretical things that may or may not exist and technologies we probably won't reach within the next millennium. But you know what, *who cares!?* It's science fiction! It's a creative endeavour!

These are questions of classic worldbuilding. The questions' wording and the expectations allude to a creative approach. Scientifically speaking, none of the fictional bird's description really has any bearing on what kind of quill can be made from it; for in the real world, I can make a quill pen out of any feather! For the other one, I doubt anyone has a clue what could really work in a situation like that.

Classic worldbuilding is, first and foremost, a creative endeavour. Comments about whether or not flamingos eat microbes is not only unhelpful, but also completely off the topic. Irrelevant. Comments focusing on where, geographically in the real world, quill pens were used are also unhelpful. Irrelevant. The only helpful comment was the one about research. Yes, research is mandatory, but this doesn't read as the kind of question where the OP needs to demonstrate a PhD in ornithology to ask a question about a fictional bird and the kind of quills that might be made from it.

If the OP were focused on microbes, then the question should be asked in BIOLOGY.SE; if the OP were focused on quill usage, then it should be asked in HISTORY.SE. But no, the OP asked here, in WB.SE, because a *different kind of answer* is needed. A more creative solution for a more creative query.

To that end, we really need to come to some sort of consensus on what "story based" means in this context, and also what "opinion based" means. And we also need to unshackle ourselves from becoming too rulebound. We are becoming SCIENCE.LITE.SE, and that is not where we should be!

**Criticisms and Considerations**: (to follow shortly...)

Comment: Hmm, there is also a writing stack exchange that I frequently see suggested as an alternative place to post opinion based questions, I'm not entirely sure how valid a suggestion that is for some of those I've seen that suggested on but there is clearly the same desire (as you express here to differentiate WBSE from all the science SEs) among some to differentiate WBSE from WSE, it may be a matter of balance, I don't pretend to be certain where that balance might be though.

Comment: @Pelinore Writing still doesn't take story suggestions/prompts. See [New rule on what to write questions](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1401) and in general [the on-topic page in their help centre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The stack is mostly about the writing *process*. Helping writers *how to write* not *what to write*. They might dip into the actual text in terms of style or similar but for the majority of cases, it's not where story questions should go. There is thus *extremely small* overlap between WB and Writing.

Comment: OK, getting back on topic > there can be a very thin line between *"story based or opinion based requiring creative solutions"* and writing their story and character choices for them (which I don't think we want to do?), but I have seen "opinion based VTC" used a little too enthusiastically (or so I thought) on questions I thought were OK, so perhaps you could expand with more detail on where you would like to see the line drawn / maybe how you think the rules or advice for opinion based etc should be worded? I think we might need that to move your topic on in any way.

Comment: [ponders] let me put that (perhaps) a little more clearly .. what parts of the guidance and advice in the help pages (etc) do you think cause the problem you think exists and how would you change them to solve the problem?

Comment: Obviously, I'm not suggesting we write a user's story. But we do have a problem with closing questions for being "opinion based" simply because it doesn't fit with real world reality. That's great for Physics.SE, not great for WB.SE. As for story based, we really need to be less fearful of good story based questions. Clearly, "here are two things, which should my character choose" is a bad question. But "hey, I'm 10k words into this magicoscientific fantasy, worldbuilding and narrative are interfacing, but I'm having a difficulty seeing how to get the plot mvoed from (cont)

Comment: (cont) set up to conclusion" is a much better question for us. it brings us back to the more robust creativity of the past rather than shoulder-shrugging dismissal of the present.

Comment: Yep, but that's still just an observation and description of what's happening that you'd like to see change, what's the cause? why are we doing it? pull up the "story based" text and the advice for using it blurb and have a read through it, what in the current wording is the cause and how might we change it to better accommodate what you think we should be doing, what's the cause and how do we fix it? without that we're just moaning to no useful effect ;)

Comment: Hmm, is [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/254217/is-it-possible-to-live-off-grid-in-the-modern-world-while-still-having-access) the sort of thing you're on about? 3 close votes for 'story based', I don't think his question *'really'* fits that interpretation exactly myself, he knows what he wants the guy to do, probably has heard people say "so and so" does it, he just doesn't understand "how" you can do what he wants him to do, that sounds like something we could call fixing his technical issue with his worldbuilding to me.

Comment: @Pelinore I think the perfect niche for Worldbuilding would be solving particular problems with a story, or world-mechanics ("why does my wizard use a staff") *even if it requires brainstorming*, which leaves Writing for questions that are rather more specifically about the actual act of writing (rules, best practices, style guides, etc) and the science exchanges can handle the strict science questions. I do think that brainstorming specific scenarios is the only sensible niche that Worldbuilding has available to occupy.

Comment: @JamieB -- Good point there! I have always disliked "opinion based" as a closure reason; have long disliked our disdain for "story based" questions and am rapidly becoming disenchanted with the whole "brainstorming" thing. Brainstorming and opinions are pretty much what we do!

Comment: @JamieB it's fine that you and elem have an opinion on that, that's great, but it does nothing to tell anyone what specifically you think needs to change in any of the site rules wording, and until one or other of you do that so theres actually something tangible to look at and discuss you are just flapping your gums to no useful purpose, I thought I'd made my point clear before but apparently not, has my being a little bit rude helped elucidate the message a little more clearly for you or am i still wasting my time?

Comment: @Pelinore --- Being rude is never the way to go. You just shut people off and demonstrate that you never had a point in the first place.

Comment: Message received load and clear, yes, I am still wasting my time, "I feel  something" is great but unless we can move it on to what we can do about that it's just moaning around the water cooler, pointeless, go back and read what I already asked you .. what in the wording of our relevant rules could be changed to facilitate any changes desired .. we already established some of us may feel some changes 'may' be good so move it on to specific suggestions for changes for us to consider and analyse the potential effect.

Comment: I'm all for this and believe we can do it, but I wonder if it makes sense to invite people to shy away from "all things fictional must be made factual" questions. Do you believe that's a reasonable request? This is likely to be the last issue addressed in all this because it's the stickiest: Too Story-Based; Opinion-Based; Real World Questions; [Help Me Engineer My Fantasy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10202/40609); I'm Suffering Writer's Block; High Concept Questions; and more.

Comment: @Pelinore --- Being snarky is also not a good way to go. You might waste less time considering a different approach in future.

Comment: @elemtilas considering that you completely ignored the 'non-snarky' approach and even seemed to pretend I hadn't said anything I might well consider taking  less time on it in future, if you don't want snark consider not ignoring the non-snark .. this needs to move on to specifics not waste more time chuntering about non specifics, it still hasn't, it's still a waste of time until it does.

Comment: @Pelinore -- I *am* going to get to your points! It's just going to take me a bit!

Comment: @elemtilas OK then :)

Comment: Agree that opinion-based and brainstorming questions should be permitted. You are right that this is the major purpose of worldbuilding. Disagree with anything anti-science. If you want to relate the feathers of the bird to the bird, that *is* a science question, specifically biology, and science-based responses would be as helpful as other perspectives. Most people ask questions about what would *make sense* in their world, and often the best, or a good way to decide what makes sense is to go to science. Science-based answers can live alongside others. (and science answers CAN BE creative)

Comment: Also, the *majority* of questions right now are asking for some science-based sanity check. Look at the front page and that's what you see. Dyson spheres, gravitational waves, mountain formation, climate. There's even one guy trying to hire someone for money to help with science advice! Most authors don't have a problem thinking up fantastical scenarios on their own, but they are concerned about accidentally writing something that would go against science, and that's why they use this place.

Comment: @causative -- **1.**  Just to clarify: I'm not proposing we go "anti-science" (and if you can point me to where I say such please do so, so I can review and edit as necessary!); and I've never said that science based answers can't be creative. I've long been a proponent of the creative approach in science here, and have also consistently advocated for the creation of a science where none exists in the real world. Case in point, the feather and quill question.

Comment: @causative -- **2.**  I have no problem with questions that ask for a science based reality check. That's not even what I'm talking about. My point specifically addresses the shift towards science as an expectation for all queries here. We have too many unhelpful comments along the lines of "this is scientifically impossible, go away"; "unrealistic, go do what you want"; "magic = opinion based, VTC". Often times a science based sanity check is not really what is helpful, and I think we have to recognise that a querent might not quite understand that science isn't always the

Comment: (cont). answer to the question. If someone asks for scientific help, that's fine. I even sent that person to an organisation that can help him out! The problem I'm addressing is not the culture of "anti-science", but rather of "anti-creativity".

Comment: @Pelinore -- **1.** On Writing.SE, I agree with you that we need to be careful sending people there. They don't deal with our kind of questions. The only people I would send there are those who clearly have questions about mechanics: grammar, word choice, writing style, publication, etc. I would *not* send them there if their question focuses on "in world writing" as we could handle that, or Conlang.SE.  I think the balance between WB and W (and really even Biology or Physics) is an 80/20 approach: that is, it's best to err on the fictional side and answer the question here, rather

Comment: @Pelinore -- than send them to one of the science forums only to have them dragon blasted for asking about something "made up". As for VLAZ's comment on W, I'd rather see a good "story prompt" or even a "plot/world" query handled here. **2.**  *The Thin Line* -- totally agreed on this point. When it comes to character choices (and this means individual characters, corporate characters like a ship's crew or a military command or a company) and when it comes to plot development, those are strict NOs in my opinion. I'd argue that character choice and plot are often affected by Rules of the World,

Comment: @Pelinore -- so just ask about the Rules of the World! I'll take your suggestion about the rabid VTC reactions under advisement. I think we're probably in agreement that VTC for opinion based is used too frequently. I'd also invite you to share where you think the line should be as well!  **3.**  I will also review the current help pages in regard to 2.  **4.**  That's the point communication broke down, so I'll leave it at three points!

Comment: @JBH --- **1.**  I think it's much more reasonable (and appropriate for this forum), to think not in terms of "all things fictional must be made factual" but rather "all things fictional **are already factual**".  This is one reason why I frequently jump on people in comments for stating that such and such a thing can't exist because of Reality.  The assumption of the first statement seems (to me) to be a. I want this thing, b. you know science, c. make this thing real.  That's not how I understand worldbuilding. It sounds a

Comment: @JBH -- little delusional to me. I think the assumption of the other perspective is: a. I've got this thing, b. you understand science & creativity, c. help me understand this thing that's I've got! Where the two perspectives differ is that one violates science while the other seeks to use science for the purpose of art. I think we just need to hammer the idea home: the more we help especially new people understand that you're world exists and we're here to help you understand it, rather than you want to make a certain kind of

Comment: @JBH --- world and we're here to build it for you, the better off we'll all be! **2.** "This is likely to be the last issue addressed in all this because it's the stickiest..." That's fair! I might have a go at some other issues as well, but as you know, it's the creativity that's closest to my heart here! If that disappears, there's really no reason for me hang around!

Comment: @elemtilas I don't disagree with you... it's the querents who disagree with you. They're out watching shows like *The Expanse* and *Interstellar* and, lacking a college education in hard science, are walking away believing the marketing for the shows and assuming that any flight of fancy can be expressed in terms of known science - if they can just find the right person to do that for them. It's insane, but after nearly two years of watching what I hoped was just a fad build in momentum, I can't but assume that we have a long row to hoe.

Answer (score 7):

### Story in questions

- Is storybuilding part of WBSE?
- can I ask about my story? (e.g. let people do a internal consistency check on my story)
- can I give story details to explain something in my question?
  you can give a "story goal" (e.g. how can my merfolk sink this ship) you want to achieve but you are missing the in world way to that goal.
- what can I do if my question was closed as "to story based"?

### Goal of the section

My goal would be to have a section people can point to when discussing whether a question should be closed as "to story based" and also for new members to check the rules about this specific (and often controverse) topic before (or after) asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

**Worldbuilding Stack Resources**

The Stack provides a number of resources to help you with your worldbuilding. Please consider reviewing these resources before asking a question.

- [Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com) is where you can ask and learn about how Stack Exchange works, Stack policies, and Stack culture. You need [one reputation point](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) to enter Meta. Thus it is accessible to every registered account.
- We provide a [list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609) with a large list of links to worldbuilding tools and help.
- We've created a [checklist for new questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624) that is the best place to start before you ask your first question. We have also provided a [catalog of question types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6130/40609) that identify the types of question we answer and those we don't.
- We have a [new question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where you can test a question before posting it on Main. This is a great way to learn about how to ask questions and how Stack Exchange's rules and the Stack policies affect questions.

Comment: Might be time to nominate someone or a team to check all the W/B resources to ensure no broken links etc.. I'm game. (If you're not already on the case that is)

Comment: Who or what is the Main site?

Comment: Don't users start with 1 reputation, with the tour page giving a badge?

Comment: I am fairly sure that the system starts with 1, and it is very hard to get to 0: you'd need to get a single accepted answer (15) which then has 8 downvotes (-16).

Comment: @Trish it's *impossible* to get below 1. If you have, say, 3 reputation and for whatever reason get rep reduction < -2 then you still only go down to 1. There is no zero, nor negative reputation a user can have.

Comment: @Jakav correct. The tour only gives [the Informed badge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed). That does not change anything for the account. At best if somebody posts something off-topic and they *don't* have the badge, they can be directed to the tour page (comment [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000): `[tour]`) as to inform themselves what the site's model is. Also a note: on some other stacks, the rep requirement for participating in meta is higher. Not a lot higher but just to stop brand new accounts. On SO it's 5 rep, for example.

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. I'm delighted with your enthusiasm. Though we're not quite ready for that yet, it'll be a big enough task that the help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AlexP If you're reading this comment, you're currently in Meta, distinguished by a grayscale color scheme. Main is the site where actual worldbuilding questions are asked, distinguished by its somewhat orangey color scheme.

Comment: @Jakav I'm not entirely sure. It's been a very long time since I was a new user. Now that you have me thinking about it, the [tour] gets you a badge, not reputation. I'll update that later today.

Comment: Oh yes I know that I am on Meta. But somebody who is reading the proposed text for the first time has no idea what you are speaking of. Might be a good idea to explain what is what before referring to them as if they were known entities.

Comment: @AlexP Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a formal write up for this, but I would like to see more specific resources for people with moderator privileges about what to do in common situations. We are given privileges, and there are instructions about their mechanics, but little training in their daily use. I think this leads to divergent ideas about how to use those privileges, something I am definitely guilty of.

I'll start with a sketch of one that's been on my mind.

## How to vote-to-close constructively

I find it off-putting to see close votes for "Needs Details Or Clarity" or "Opinion Based" (always an odd one here) or "Needs More Focus" with no explanations. The questioner should have the opportunity to adjust their question, but how can they with only a vague idea what the problem is?

As much as we hope they would, people cannot be expected to study the Tour and Help Center before asking. And one can never assume the VTC reason is obvious. Rather than expecting people to know all the rules or read our minds, we should focus on correction and education.

This could include...

### A linkable reference of common close reasons and their remedies

For each specific type of reason for closing, we could have a page discussing it, and suggestions for how the question could be fixed. VTCers would be encouraged to add a comment linking to the appropriate page.

This would be mentioned in the help pages about closing.

This could be as simple as specially tagged meta questions. For example, I frequently reference [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on Stack Overflow.

This allows everyone to pool their efforts into building a collective reference of both very specific close reasons, and also their specific solutions. Rather than asking each VTCer to write a big explanation, they can link to the reference making it as easy as possible to provide clarity and instruction.

Comment: These are good ideas and some of it has been worked on. For example, we have a [catalog of question types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6130/40609), but until now, we've had no ability to get it into the [help]. To be honest, this is our chance to link from the [help] to editable meta pages where we can more easily control the pages and keep policies up to date. We've been lacking that.

Comment: @JBH Agreed. Doesn't matter how much helpful content exists if people don't know to go looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Site-Specific Policies**

Every Stack is a little different. These differences are often reflected in the site's policies. Below is a short list of the most important policies. You can find a complete list by [clicking here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com).

- We do not answer questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds. [[1](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7336/40609)]
- We accept real-world questions with a worldbuilding context. [[2](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609)], [[5](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/help-me-understand-the-required-level-and-relevance-of-worldbuilding-context-i)]
- We do not accept brainstorming or idea-generation questions. [3]
- We do not accept questions about character or organizational decisions or choices. [4]
- We allow answers that address problems with the question. Such answers are called [Frame Challenges](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609) and must contain specific types of information to be valid.
- We do not accept questions presenting a seemingly small or minor change with a request for evaluations of broad consequences (e.g., "if Hitler died of pneumonia one year earlier, how would that have affected World War II?"). We call these [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609).

---

**NOTE:** I'm using some existing policies (and two that aren't...) to demonstrate the proposed section. I expect some policies may change as a result of this effort. I believe the specifics of what should be here is a discussion for later.

Comment: When we removed the custom close option for idea generation all the discussion around removing it was because it was covered by other existing close reasons. Idea generation was still not permitted after the change.

Comment: @sphennings I'm sure you're right and maybe raw idea generation should still be off-topic, but that's a discussion for later when we ask ourselves which, if any, of our policies should be modified. Today I'm just using it as a placeholder to exemplify the need for the section.

Comment: "We accept real-world questions", caveat, providing there's [Worldbuilding context](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/help-me-understand-the-required-level-and-relevance-of-worldbuilding-context-i).

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. I had forgotten all about that post! One of my goals with this is to start linking all the relevant policy posts so we don't have to remember everything. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Bullet 4: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49 - our "too story based" policy.

Comment: "*You can find a complete list by clicking here.*" the link just leads to the main page. Is that intended to be a placeholder for something else? Or is the link wrong?

Comment: @Trish I didn't include that in this example intentionally. I expect we'll have a rigorous discussion of what "too story-based" means in the future. Please remember that this first effort is focusing on major divisions (although I'm not surprised that folks want to jump into the details).

Comment: @VLAZ That's because a landing page listing all our policies doesn't yet exist. At this time policies are considered "in review." Please remember that this first post's intent is to review major divisions on the [help/on-topic] page. To use that page efficiently, we will need to link out to Meta pages that deal with the main section in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I was just checking if it was intentional or an accidental omission.

Comment: That would be worth a note then - that "TSB" might need a revamp.

Comment: I notice there's a lot of "we DO NOT accept questions..." but only one "we DO accept questions...". I think we need more positive guidance on what to is good to ask.

Answer (score -4):

Don't waste your time.

The Stack Exchange model of curation and moderation is predicated on small communities where the majority of members understand and share that community's rules and goals. Because of this, compliance is high, community participation in curation is high, and active moderation is rarely required since the community is self-policing.

As the various sites in the SE network have grown in user count, this model has very obviously begun to fail. Few of the new users are interested in becoming part of the community by e.g. reading the help pages; they don't care about such things as "rules" because each one is a special snowflake who expects their question to be answered. Over time the ratio of curators:users thus decays to the point that the workload on the remaining curators becomes such that many cease curating. This leads to more work for fewer curators, which accentuates burnout, which creates a negative loop whereby curation activities ultimately cease because nobody is interested in dealing with the torrent of rule violations that non-compliant users call "questions".

This could be overcome if Stack Exchange moderators had the ability to unilaterally remove content they believe violates site policy - but they very crucially lack that ability. In contrast, moderation in pretty much every other community on the web grants that sort of ability. Guess which of these two models has been around since the invention of the internet **because it works**? I'll give you a clue, *it's not Stack Exchange's one*.

So yeah, you and the mod team can go ahead and bail a few cupfuls of water out the side of this particular site-boat by updating the help pages. But when you have hundreds of new users throwing cupfuls of water in the other side, what exactly do you expect is ultimately going to happen to the boat?

For anyone who thinks I'm being unduly negative or doom-and-gloomy... I've experienced this on Stack Overflow, where I estimate that currently *at least* a third of the questions are unfettered garbage, and that percentage is trending swiftly upwards. Is Worldbuilding likely to experience the same thing? Almost certainly; it's never going to have the same number of new users as SO, but it's also never going to have as many curators, and the number of bad questions that remain open here nowadays - because nobody flags them for closure - is already horrifying.

Comment: "Over time the ratio of curators:users thus decays to the point that the workload on the remaining curators becomes such that many cease curating. This leads to more work for fewer curators, which accentuates burnout, which creates a negative loop...." Do you have any evidence to support this assertion which would apply to worldbuilding (our demographic is a bit different from Stackoverflow after all)- or is it just an opinion?

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. (great nick BTW) Considering that most of the questions on here that should be closed aren't, the ratio of curators:users is evidently already problematic.

Comment: @IanKemp Do you have any evidence that most of the questions that should be closed aren't? Who decides which should be closed? What issues are being caused by their remaining open?

Comment: I'm going to amplify that last bit, what's the harm if a question is left open? If others didn't feel the need to vtc, maybe it wasn't so bad. Downvotes should quickly send it to the bottom; what's the issue if it's not crowding out other questions? Being too restrictive can suppress *all* questions. Closing a question too quickly, or for a non-obvious reason, can leave the asker discouraged from fixing their question or asking another. Unilateral close power leads to arbitrary decisions and more bad feelings. To continue to be welcoming and inclusive, we need to accept some crap.

Comment: @Schwern Part of the problem is SE's own goals. They *want* rapid closure and even deletion of questions (you can't delete once the first answer is posted). Why? They *want* to become the world's go-to source for knowledgeable, experienced answers you can't get elsewhere. In other words, we're fighting the intent of the site when we just let things slide. Most of us signed on back when this was, perhaps, a bigger deal than it is today... but we still see the value in it. Trust me, we'll never crowd out all questions - even on this stack. It's also worth noting SE was intended for adults. ...

Comment: @Schwern Also, keep in mind that closing a question was *never* intended to be a punishment. Querents (remember, intended for adults) are expected to work with the community to figure out what went wrong and actively fix it, thereby becoming better at asking questions. What doesn't work? It's rude to say it, but folks under the age of 25 or folks who only care about getting a quick answer (free research service!) rather than becoming part of the community.

Comment: @IanKemp Hey, I *want* more gold badges (who doesn't), but most days there are only at most 4 to 6 reviews in the close review queue. Most days I read all the questions posted and most answers - we don't have the volume of SO or the bigger sites There are many lurking high-rep users who seldom post, but stick around for interest, I see that when I check-out the "last visited" in their profiles- myself included, only having posted twice this year, and about once a month last year. We seem to be OK for curators here as far as I can tell.

Comment: I would argue that Worldbuilding's problem in particular is that we have rules that don't make sense, were interpreted very differently 5 years ago, and even the old curmudgeons that try to enforce their version of the rules can be seen blatantly breaking them in their own post history. We have a problem with consistency and arbitrary definitions. Any revamp of the help pages should also reconsider the rules, and try to reinvent this place as something that makes more sense from the start.

Comment: @JamieB you remain a rare voice of reason on this site

Comment: @JBH 1) I don't agree that deleting and closing is the only way to achieve that. So long as good questions and good answers continue to float to the top we're good. 2) Wanting to be the go-to Q&A archive is inherited from SO. That might make sense for technical questions with clear, repeated questions and answers, does it make sense for WB.SE where every situation is a lot fuzzier? I think a WB pattern library would be fun, but I think those patterns will emerge from the Q&A, rather than trying to make Q&A conform to patterns. I think that needs to be rethought.

Comment: @JBH How close votes are *perceived* is what is important. I'm more concerned that your comment reads like "the user is the problem" (also ageist, which should be rejected) which is a sign of burn out. If we have contempt for new users, we're done. If we're burnt out, step aside for a while and let someone fresh take a crack at it. We need to work *with* new users and give them the chance to be awesome and the space to learn ***in a safe, pleasant, encouraging experience*** because who wants to hang around miserable people? We're all doing this for free.

Comment: @JBH We need to acknowledge that there is a tension between our long term goals (making a definitive Q&A archive, or whatever) and short goals (solving immediate problems, writing fun answers, etc). When a casual user asks a question, they're focused on their situation, not the site's long term goals; it's natural they just want their problem solved, and it's natural to be a bit miffed if we close their question because of some long term goals that are not theirs. So yes, people will be focused on getting answers, and we need to minimize the tension with our long term goals.

Comment: @Schwern If people just want to ask and answer worldbuilding questions without restrictions there are plenty of other sites. What makes us unique is that we provide a much more structured format. I think a lot of the problem is that people come to us expecting something else. To my understanding this also happens on SO and contributes to the idea that SO is a hostile place. It is rough to ask for help and be told you're not asking the right way. However this structure is what made SO special. By needing to fit the format, I have to organize my thoughts which often makes the answer obvious.

Comment: Good SO answers don't just solve the problem but explain and provide context. I think that's the result of the limitations on the sort of programming questions they accept. Imagine if we could explain to a worldbuilder why certain materials can only be manufactured in microgravity. Right now we get questions asking "What would be manufactured in space in my world, given my supertechnology?" They're similar questions but the first is reusable. The second isn't and also requires us to guess at all the other reasons something could be manufactured in space.

Comment: @sphennings Agreed, I'm not looking for a site with no restrictions; quite the opposite: constraints will set you free. Rather than focusing on how can we close more questions, we should be focusing on how do we get everyone on board with our goals (after we agree what it is) while still getting their immediate question answered (or at least not shut down in a way that feels harsh). How to train the community to ask questions which get better answers (their need) and avoid draining our collective resources (our need), while also expanding by getting more people to stick around.

Comment: @Schwern "Getting more people to stick around" is becoming a real worry of mine. We're down to 4.8 questions per day according to the ratings. That puts us just above "Biblical Hermeneutics". Worldbuilding should be a broad and fun site. And it used to be, and the rules were nearly identical back then. I think any rule revision should look to return us to the glory days of 5 years ago, simply by rewording the rules to match how they were interpreted back then.

Comment: I would argue that many questions are being closed when they should be left open. It's not so much the ratio of curators to users, but the highly subjective metrics of the curators themselves.

Comment: @JamieB -- Since this particular response is nosediving, and you do bring up excellent points, could I persuade you to work your points into a separate response?